# Display data which is found by findAllByPk Yii

Tags: php, yii

```
$arr1 = array(1,3);
$provider_type_details= self::model()->findAllByPk($arr1);
echo $provider_type_details->provider_type;
```

This is my code.I am not able to print the data provider_type from `$provider_type_details`.By the way when printing the details of `$provider_type_details` by using `print_r($provider_type_details);` it is possible to view `provider_type`.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`findAllByPk`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByPk-detail) returns an array of objects and not an object. You can loop through the array `echo`ing all `provider_type`s.